# Why isnt this simple "rock paper scissors" program working in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to write a program in which the user plays rock paper scissors against the computer. However, I don't know why it isn't working. Here's the code:

```
import random

computerResult = random.randint(1,3)

print("Lets play Rock Paper Scissors")
playerResult = input("Type 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors: ")

if computerResult == 1:
    print("Computer says Rock")
if computerResult == 2:
    print("Computer says Paper")
if computerResult == 3:
    print("Computer says Scissors")


if playerResult == computerResult:
    print("Its a draw")
elif playerResult == 1 and computerResult == 2:
    print("You lose")
elif playerResult == 1 and computerResult == 3:
    print("You win")
elif playerResult == 2 and computerResult == 1:
    print("You win")
elif playerResult == 2 and computerResult == 3:
    print("You lose")
elif playerResult == 3 and computerResult == 1:
    print("You lose")
elif playerResult == 3 and computerResult == 2:
    print("You win")
```

When I run the program and play the game this is what i get:

```
Lets play Rock Paper Scissors
Type 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors: 1
Computer says Scissors
```

It doesn't say whether I won or lost and I cant figure out why

Comment: `input` returns a string... You are comparing against an integer?

Comment: `input()` is getting a string and you are comparing to int with `if playerResult == 1`

Answer (score 6):

Because `playerResult` is a `str` and `computerResult` is `int`. And comparing string to int always results in `False`

Change

```
playerResult = input("Type 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors: ")
```

To

```
playerResult = int(input("Type 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors: "))
```

Comment: @Mr.goosberry Well, the question was "I don't understand why it's not working", not "What is the way to make it work", so, while it's admittedly less helpful, a literal "Here's why it's not working" answer is pretty appropriate, I think...

Comment: @twalberg yes. I think I'd have to agree with you on that one.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it

```
playerResult = input("Type 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors: ")
playerResult = int(playerResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is is that your assuming the `input()` function returns a integer. It does not, it returns a **string**. Change this line

`playerResult = input("Type 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors: ")`

to this:

`playerResult = int(input("Type 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors: "))`

With the `int()` function you are converting your input to a integer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be fixed casting the user input to an integer.

I'll also add a check to handle the bad input casistic:

```
goodResult = False
```

playerResult = 0

```
while not goodResult:

    inp = input("Type 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper or 3 for Scissors: ")

    try:
        playerResult = int(inp)
        goodResult = (playerResult > 0 and playerResult < 4)

    except:
        goodResult = False
```